# Subtracting min and max values from ListBox to find range

Tags: vb.net

I can't seem to subtract the max from the min does anyone know how I can fix this.

Code:

```
Do While (rngNumbers < lstSize - 1)
    rngNumbers += 1
    If CBool(CDbl(lstAverage.Items(CInt(rngNumbers > max)))) Then
        max = CInt(lstAverage.Items(rngNumbers))
    ElseIf CBool(CDbl(lstAverage.Items(CInt(rngNumbers < min)))) Then
        min = CInt(lstAverage.Items(rngNumbers))
    End If
Loop
grdRange = max - min
txtRange.Text = grdRange.ToString
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look like very good code besides but I think that this:

```
If CBool(CDbl(lstAverage.Items(CInt(rngNumbers > max)))) Then
```

should be this:

```
If CDbl(lstAverage.Items(rngNumbers)) > max Then
```

This is a scenario that is more suited to a `For Each` loop:

```
For Each num As Double In lstAverage.Items
    If num > max Then
        max = num
    ElseIf num < min Then
        min = num
    End If
Next
```

You're using `CDbl` and `CInt` in your original code so I don't know whether you're working with `Double` or `Integer` values.  I've used `Double` in that example but it will work the same with `Integer` if your `ListBox` contains `Integers`.  Hopefully it does contain one or the other and not `Strings`.